# How to linq filter on multiple GUID at once generating an appropriate sql where clause

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, fluent

I'm having a hard time generating a properly filtered sql query with fluent API in **Entity Framework core rc2-final** connected to a **sqlite** database.

I have the following simple entity :

```cs
public class Thing
{
    [Required, Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to query the database for all books that are in a stash list of Books I provide. So far, sounds easy. This is how we could write it :

```cs
// 'GetShortListFromSomewhere' returns 2 items that ALREADY exist in db
List<Thing> externalList = GetShortListFromSomewhere();
var result = db.Things.Where(thing => externalList.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();
```

But the following query is generated which is kind of correct and kind of .. not .. for sqlite :

```sql
SELECT "o"."Id", "o"."Name" FROM "Thing" AS "o"
    WHERE "o"."Id" IN ('7edbc016-abfa-4005-83d1-b39618b047df', '2def16bb-4203-417d-847c-7bdf053a00e8')
```

As expected in code, this returns me 0 items although Ids are perfectly valid. Guid on Sqlite as stored on Blob and although EF-Core seems to handle the filter nicely for single item filter, it doesn't seem to handle it in this case.

How can I get around this issue knowing that I need it to be a sql operation ?

ps: Last thing I want is for EF Core to download the whole Thing collection from db and then filter it ! It would be madness in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue [#5801](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5801). Unfortunately, it won't be fixed for the 1.0.0 release. To workaround, map the columns to `byte[]` properties.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Mapping the columns to `byte[]` properties would be a big job in my project. We have close to 100 entities with at least 2 Guids per entity. And many many references to these guids. Without looking too close at how to proceed next, it can already foresee a nice headache. "For now" (tm) I might go for an aberration like `externalList.Foreach(externalItem => db.Things.Where(o => externalItem.Id == o.Id))`.. Sends shivers down your spine too, right ? :)

Comment: The fix is also in the [nightly builds](http://myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext) now, if that's an option...

Comment: Yes, much better indeed. I know we're far away from production time for version 1.0.1, but do you think an official nuget version will be available by September ? In the meantime, I'll accept this answer as it is the best option at this time.

Comment: I can't answer that. ;-) But last I heard, we're striving for about the same cadence as VS updates--every three to four months.